# Due to an error "HCA: SDD PROCEDURE ERROR: 3013 - RECORD LENGTH MISMATCH", the GDS Travelport 1V - Apollo Booking API failed

Tags: travelport-api

Our queries to Travelport support team: For [Air Create Reservation API](https://apac.universal-api.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/AirService)

> An error occurred in the booking confirmation scenario. Please review
> the error provided below. **Error Response:** "HCA: SDD PROCEDURE ERROR: 3013 -
> RECORD LENGTH MISMATCH"

Answer (score 0):

Travelport Response from [Travelport Support team Link](https://travelportprod.service-now.com/mytravelport_support/):

> Generally this error - "Error from HCA: SDD PROCEDURE ERROR: 3013 -
> RECORD LENGTH MISMATCH" is returned when there are too many SSR in the
> request. Additionally, I can see lot of SSRs, General and Accounting
> Remark in your request.
>
> You can get more information about SSRs here:
> https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/uAPI.htm#Air/Shared_Air_Topics/SSRs_(Special_Service_Requests).htm?Highlight=SSR
>
> More information about remarks can be found here:
> https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/uAPI.htm#Booking/UniversalRecord/Remarks_Overview.htm%3FTocPath%3DUniversal%2520Records%2520and%2520Bookings%7CAssociated%2520Topics%7CRemarks%7C_____0
>
> As for your attached transaction I see it is going as 4530 in
> length[SDD data]. This error is as per designed.